# How to get the checkboxes dynamically in android?

Tags: android

In my project I need to **display questions and its options**. **Here the options are at max 20 with multiple answers.** The options are not fixed for each question. That means for each question the options may be 2 or 3 or 6 or 18 or 2o. **Since the question contains multiple answers I need to create checkboxes to display options dynamically.** Based on the number of options for the question we need to display the checkboxes. How can I do that? Please help me regarding this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an empty LinearLayout and call its addView() function
to add the checkboxes dynamically in your code.

For example,

```
CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[20]; // Number varies..
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
    cbs[i]  = new CheckBox(this);
    ll.addView(cb); 
    cbs.setText("Test");
 }
```

Look at this turorial [Android, Part III: Dynamic Layouts](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/130521-android-part-iii-dynamic-layouts/)

**EDIT:**

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

 CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[20]; 
for(x=1; x<numberofoptions; x++)
 { 
   cbs[x] = new CheckBox(getContext()); 
   ll.addView(cbs[x]); 
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code. I have tried like rl =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rlt_layout);  CheckBox[] cbs = new CheckBox[20];  for(x=1; x<numberofoptions; x++){
  cbs[x]  = new CheckBox(getContext());         
rl.addView(cbs[x]);  } but it is displaying only 1 checkbox..plz help me where i am going wrong

Comment: Hi thanks for the response...I tried like that but it is not displaying the checkboxes still....where i am going wrong?

Comment: Welcome anytime.. Happy coding.. :-)

Comment: Hi I need to get the id's of those dynamically displayed checkboxes. I  tried but chk.getId() is not working. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Just set ID of check box at time of creation checkbox in loop. like, cbs[x].setId(x); and the you can get ID with cbs[x].getId()..